# Just started using Unity from Ubuntu Classic. Missing Indicators

Tags: 11.04, unity, 11.10, indicator

I just moved to Ubuntu Unity and found my Indicators missing (11.04)

[image]

Also I have tried Installing Ubuntu 11.10 CLI (using Alternate CD), then `install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop`. I remember all indicators are missing.

I think those I want are:

- Network
- Clock
- Session (to shutdown)
- Email (ThunderBird & Chat in 11.10)
- Synapse
- Dropbox
- Lookit

For 11.04 and 11.10 how can I get back my indicators? For 11.04, I have those indicators when using Ubuntu Classic so is there some conflict or something?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the result of the `--no-install-recommends` option you used. Installing a matapackage usually requires all of its dependencies, including the recommended, otherwise some features will be missing. If you want to use Unity, install it, on the other hand, if you want a minimal setup, use LXDE.

Comment: Yes so what am I missing? Like the required packages. Looking at the packages http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/ubuntu-desktop and http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/ubuntu-desktop, I don't really see what I might need. For example, I think the shutdown indicator is `indicator-session` but I don't see that as a package

Comment: Here you go `http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/indicator-session`. Not every package directly depends on `ubuntu-desktop`, some may depend on the packages `ubuntu-desktop` pulls in.